# Clipboard.GetDataObject() always returns null

Tags: c#, clipboard, clipboarddata

I am struggling with using clipboard to copy / paste object, so I created a very simple example to demonstrate the issue.

What is very frustrating is that the same code was working earlier and stopped recently and I am unable to figure out what is wrong.

Basically, the problem is that dataObject.GetData() always returns null even if dataObject.GetDataPresent() returned true earlier.

I am running on .Net 4.5.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a = new TestClass();
        a.Name = "Test";
        a.Index = 1;
        a.Live = true;
        IDataObject dataObj = new DataObject();

        // Method 1 : Not working

        //dataObj.SetData(a);

        // Method 2 : also not working

        DataFormats.Format format = DataFormats.GetFormat(a.GetType().FullName);
        dataObj.SetData(format.Name, false, a);


        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj, false);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDataObject dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

        // Method 1 : Not working

        //if (dataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(TestClass)))
        //{
        //  // Issue => retrievedObj is ALWAYS null
        //  var retrievedObj = dataObject.GetData(typeof(TestClass));
        //}

        // Method 2 : also not working

        if (dataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(TestClass).FullName))
        {
            // Issue => retrievedObj is ALWAYS null
            var retrievedObj = dataObject.GetData(typeof(TestClass).FullName);
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Name;
    public int Index;
    public bool Live;
}
}
```

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Try putting `[Serializable]` above the `public class TestClass` line.  Prefer public properties to public fields.  Did you mean to use Name instead of FullName?

Comment: Lars is correct. Also, no need to bother with IDataObject. `Clipboard.SetData(typeof(TestClass).FullName, a);` and `var a2 = Clipboard.GetData(typeof(TestClass).FullName) as TestClass;`

Comment: Yep, Serializable resolves the issue which makes very sad in fact. It is sad, because  I have reduced a much more difficult code to this sample, and in the original code I have the serializable attribute set on the class in question. So although this works, it does not resolve my original issue :) This is the problem with simplification of a complex code...

Comment: We can only help you with the code you provide us.

Comment: Absolutely, my bad not providing the correct code to fully reconsrtuate the issue

Comment: Just a short update : as soon as I reference a class from another assembly - which I am using XmlSerialzer with so I am sure it is serializable - the above example fails. My question, whether is it enough if XmlSerializer operates on the class successfully, or should it be perhaps binary serializable ?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question to share my experience.

To keep a long story short, in the original code I wanted to copy / paste an object that was referencing an type (XmlFont, a wrapper type I created to allow serialization of Font type) which was not explicitly marked with Serializable attribute. The funny part though, is that this object was successfully serialized to / from a file using XmlSerializer, so this part is still unclear for me. But marking the XmlFont type as Serializable instantly solved the problem.